# WYSIWYG again, IE simplest execCommand

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, execcommand

I wrote the simplest WYSIWYG in js/jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/XnSWF/

Works perfectly (eg. set to write in bold or set bold on selected text) on newset Opera 11, Chrome 16, Firefox 9 and Safari 5.1 but in IE9 I can't set bold to selected text and always when i use bold button, this carret go to first line to first letter...

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the selection is destroyed before the `click` event fires in IE. You can get round this by using the the `mousedown` event instead, or (better) by making the button text unselectable:

```
$('<li class="wysiwyg-bold"><b unselectable="on">textBold</b></li>')
    .appendTo('.wysiwyg-toolbar');
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XnSWF/1/

Comment: Big thanks! Work good with unselectable attribute, but I try remove this attribute and 'click' replace with 'mousedown' and works only with selected text not writing bolded, why? (http://jsfiddle.net/XnSWF/3/)

Comment: @kicaj: Because it still loses the selection, it just gets the bolding in first.