# What is the Internet Explorer Command Identifiers for H1, H2 and so on?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I was looking through the MSDN library for these tags but couldn't find any reference. Do these identifiers exist? If not, is there a way to define a custom HTML tag?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533049(v=vs.85).aspx

Example ussage: `doc.execCommand("FontSize", false, (object)e.Button.Text);`

Comment: See http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp; these are not IE-specific things, and you cannot add to them and expect them to be understood (except by JS/CSS you write)

Comment: [Headings](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/headings.html) ?

Comment: I attached a link to what I'm referring to.

Comment: I've never heard of "command identifiers".  What *exactly* are you trying to do?  What do these have to do with `<h1>` tags?  Aren't "custom HTML tags" made with: `document.createElement('tag')` (which is I think what the [html5shiv](https://github.com/aFarkas/html5shiv) does)?

Comment: @RocketHazmat see the link at the bottom of the post

Comment: @eis: I think I'm more confused now.

Comment: @eis I read the link, but I'm still confused. I generally don't like when people avoid answering the question, but it seems as if the original posted is using an IE-specific extension, which can be better solved with standard functionality.

Comment: I have no idea what `execCommand` does, but wouldn't something like `doc.style.fontSize(e.Button.Text)` work?

Comment: The question seems to be about [IE Platform proprietary APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh772402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that are used when you control IE internal elements programmatically (from javascript as well as from other Windows objects). If you do it from, say, another Windows application, I don't think there's anything more standard.

Comment: Interesting...apparently document.execCommand() has been added to the HTML5 standard. I guess I still learn something new every day - http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/editing.html#editing-apis

Comment: @NoahR I'm trying to help you out here, but you're not helping yourself. Could you please spell out **exactly** what you hope to accomplish? Otherwise, this question is going to get closed.

Comment: So when a portion of text is selected I want there to be <h1> tag wrapped around the selected text. There are command identifiers that do this for almost every general HTML but H tags. If I wanted to make some text bold I could use doc.execCommand("Bold", false, (object)e.Button.Text);

Comment: @NoahR: You might be able to hack it up with `document.getSelection()` to wrap it in an `<h1>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the existing identifiers in mshtmcid.h (here [wine version as example](http://source.winehq.org/source/include/mshtmcid.h)). From there:

```
#define IDM_APPLYHEADING1                 2255
#define IDM_APPLYHEADING2                 2256
#define IDM_APPLYHEADING3                 2257
```

Edit: it seems though you did not look for exactly that, but a javascript equivalent. If you look at the [mozilla reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla#Executing_Commands), they have two things available for it:

> formatBlock
>
> Adds an HTML block-style tag around the line containing the current selection, replacing the block element containing the line if
>   one exists (in Firefox, BLOCKQUOTE is the exception - it will wrap any
>   containing block element). Requires a tag-name string to be passed in
>   as a value argument. Virtually all block style tags can be used (eg.
>   "H1", "P", "DL", "BLOCKQUOTE"). (Internet Explorer supports only
>   heading tags H1 - H6, ADDRESS, and PRE, which must also include the
>   tag delimiters < >, such as "<H1>".)
>
> heading
>
> Adds a heading tag around a selection or insertion point line. Requires the tag-name string to be passed in as a value argument (i.e.
>   "H1", "H6"). (Not supported by Internet Explorer.)

so if you use IE, based on that information you should use `formatBlock`.

To demonstrate, I borrowed jsfiddle done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053263/wysiwyg-again-ie-simplest-execcommand) and I [added it a button that does the thing asked for](http://jsfiddle.net/9ekL5/1/). It does it by executing this code:

```
iframe.contentWindow.document.execCommand('formatBlock', false, '<H1>');
```

which is working on my IE9.

Comment: What in the world? How is this relevant?

Comment: @NoahR you asked for the command identifiers, and like you can see in the link you provided, they're defined in .h files. I've just given you the command identifiers for headings 1-3, isn't that what you asked for?

Comment: @NoahR: Can you try to explain what you *really* want and why you think you need to use command identifiers for it?  Your question seems to be asking multiple different things.

Comment: But you can't take this and put into the usage example above replacing the FontSize with IDM_APPLYHEADING1

Comment: @NoahR: `FontSize` seems to be defined as `IDM_FONTSIZE`, so maybe you need to try with `ApplyHeading1` (or something)?

Comment: @NoahR You're right. FontSize isn't a command identifier, it's a javascript command equivalent. So you're not searching for command identifiers then.

Comment: @NoahR updated now my answer for javascript commands.